# WebGrid all buttons submits the form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, webgrid

I have a grid within a form-tag. Each row in the grid has two buttons, wich of one is of type submit. I thought that only the submit button would fire of the form submission. But all buttons actually post the form.

Why is that? What's the reason to have the **type="submit"** tag if it's not taken into account?
And how could I solve this? I need multiple buttons in some of my grids.

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller"))
    {
           Html.RenderPartial("_TestGrid");
    }
```

And the buttons in this grid:

```
grid.Column(format: @<text><button>Do something</button></text>), 
grid.Column(format: @<text><button type="submit" value="1">Do something else</button></text>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use    `<input/>`  insted of `<button>`

```
grid.Column(format: @<text><input type="button" value="Somthing"/></text>), 
grid.Column(format: @<text><<input type="submit" value="Save"/></text>)
```